# nodejs - images stop loading after a time (seems to be auto deleting)

Tags: node.js

so guys, im uploading images with multer and sending it to the uploads folder. Everything works well when I upload it, but after some time, the images stop loading and If I go to the images url it says Cannot GET /uploads/2022-04-22T04:18:51.235Zhot-potato.jpeg.

I dont know what is happening, if its auto deleting from the server or what, Im using heroku..

my code is:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, './uploads/')
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
  cb(null, new Date().toISOString()+file.originalname.replace(' ', ''))
} })
var upload = multer({ 
    storage: storage,
    limits: { fileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 }, //5mb
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(null, false);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: my uploads folder is accessible from the frontend, btw.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku Heroku does not have persistent storage by default.

Comment: ah ok, thank you.